# Expand bzr branch to include parent folder

Tags: bazaar

I have the following directory structure:

> Documents
>    ----Incoming
>    ----Originals
>    ----Processed
>    ----Working

Originally I thought I only wanted to track `Working`, so I made a bzr repo in there.

Now I've decided that I actually want to track the whole folder. How do I expand the repository to include the parent directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new branch in *Documents*, temporarily move the *Working* directory somewhere else, use [`bzr merge-into`](https://launchpad.net/bzr-merge-into) to merge it back to *Documents*.

Comment: I take it that should read:  
 (1) Move `working` somewhere else temporarily;
(2) use `bzr init` to make a new branch in `documents`; (3) `bzr add .` and `bzr commit` to commit the rest of the folders into the branch; (4) then use `bzr merge-into` to merge `working` into `documents

Comment: Hrm. I see that `merge-into` is a plugin. I've never looked at the bzr plugins; now it seems as though perhaps I should.

Comment: *sigh* it turns out that this doesn't do what I need, because of other requirements I hadn't realised I had at the time - namely, I need to make a lightweight checkout of just the Documents folder.

This was the best answer to the problem I thought I had though

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't.  You can "work around" it by moving everything in your repo to a newly-created `Working` directory, then add the other directories, but if that's too ugly for you then you need to create a new repo that has everything you want in it in the right place to begin with.